# Pascal - zombie process remains after fork

Tags: fork, pascal, freepascal, zombie-process

I've written a multitreaded tcp server using `fpFork()` call. Works fine, but after client disconnects a zombie process remains. There is an infinite loop where I wait for incoming connection, fork, pass this conenction to the child, which take care of it and then exits. However the child remains as zombie until the parent terminates.

```
while True do
  begin
  // Accept connection
  ClientAddrLen := sizeof(ClientAddr);
  ClientSock := fpaccept(ServerSock, @ClientAddr, @ClientAddrLen);

  if ClientSock > 0 then // Success?
    begin

      Pid := fpFork();
      // Error fork
      if pid < 0 then
        begin
          CloseSocket(ClientSock);
          continue;
        end
      // Child process
      else if pid = 0 then
        begin
          CloseSocket(ServerSock);
          handleClient(ClientSock);
          CloseSocket(ClientSock);
          Halt(0);
        end
      // parent process
      else if pid > 0 then
        begin
          CloseSocket(ClientSock);
          continue;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

I headr about function `fpWait()` or `fpWaitPid()` but free pascal documentation lacks examples and googling it is worthless, thus I don't even how to use it.
I'm using fpc 2.6.4 on FreeBSD.

**Update 1**
After some trial-and-error testing, reading manuals and discussions I tried some combinations. I put following functions in the parent part of executed code:

```
else if pid > 0 then
  begin
    CloseSocket(ClientSock);
    //here
    continue;
  end;
```

a) Using `WaitProcess(pid)` (is equivalet with `fpWaitPid(pid, @Status, 0)`)

With this parent process wait for the child, however as the parent was waiting it couldn't accept another connection until the child is terminated.

b) Using `fpWaitPid(pid, @Status, WNOHANG)`

This function does not block the program, but it doesn't bother doing anything. Like the function is not even there. It's confusing, because everywhere i read about this (it was coded in C,but it doe's not matter, these functions are only wrappers around unix calls) was suggested use of this.

At this point I have no idea what could be wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: All those fp* functions are normal unix functions with "fp" prefix to avoid conflicts (like for read, write and open)..  fpwaitpid is a wrapper around wait that loops for common causes, comes from Richard Stevens iirc.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Good point, I did some trial-and-error experiemting, but nothing seems to work. I'll explain it in my question

Comment: I'm no real expert in forking servers( I prefer the threading approach), but I would double check your scenario matches forking server skeletons to the letter, maybe there is a need to dup the handles or some other extra processing that is required.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Treads could be better solution than this, but I'm completely unfamiliar with threading in pascal. If you could point me right drection.

Comment: For sockets based on threading, the logical direction would be to reuse or at least look at some ready made socket suites.   Mostly indy and synapse and to a lesser degree the unportable ICS (that also exist for Delphi).

Answer (score 3):

When child process was ended it's bacame a zombee and system sending the `SIGCHLD` signal to the parent process.  Parent process have will call `wait` (`fpwait` in freepascal) function when it accept the `SIGCHLD` signal. If parent process call `wait` function system send to parent process exit code of the child process and erase it's record and free it's pid.

If parent process  don't react on `SIGCHLD` signals and (or) don't call wait function then zombee process's quantity will multiply until the parent process's termination.

```
procedure DoSigChld;  cdecl;
var stat : longint;
begin
  fpwait(stat);
end;

SignalAction.sa_handler := @DoSigChld;
fpsigaction(SIGCHLD, @SignalAction, nil);
```

Comment: This is the right answer, I don't know why it got downvoted. Note that setting SIGCHLD action to SIG_IGN works just as well. See http://www.microhowto.info/howto/reap_zombie_processes_using_a_sigchld_handler.html